# How Angular handle data from Spring JPA Data with REST

Tags: json, angular, spring, rest, spring-data-jpa

I follow the spring official links build a rest server with jpa. This works fine with browser oder chrome postman extension.

https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And want use Angular to show and handle data. That is based on angular official hero example.

But I can't handle response from Spring JPA rest server.
Because the format is HAL - Hypertext Application Language.
That looks like :

```
        {

      "_embedded" : {

        "persons" : [ {

          "firstName" : "name1",

          "lastName" : "name2",

          "_links" : {

            "self" : {

              "href" : "http://localhost:8080/persons/1"

            },

            "person" : {

              "href" : "http://localhost:8080/persons/1"

            }

          }

        }, 

.......
```

There is no ID in persons array.

How can I handle this format with angular?
Should I write javascript code by my self?
If so, how to get the original JSON data from the result of angular httpclient?

I tried write spring controller to return normal JSON for Angular and that works.
But in this way I lost the benefit of Spring JPA Repository such as PagingAndSortingRepository, CrudRepository and JpaRepository.

I want keep pure spring and angular features and just change angular service to get the data.

Answer (score 2):

I think I may talk about this problem not clearly. So I study this problem again. 
the original spring jpa rest example gives the result like
[image]

after getter and setter of ID for Person class and add implement of interface RepositoryRestConfigurer

```
//@Configuration
public class ExposeAllRepositoryRestConfiguration implements RepositoryRestConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//      RepositoryRestConfigurer.super.configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(config);
        config.exposeIdsFor(Person.class);
    }
}
```

(there are some method can add all model classes)

i get this

[image]

with your method can I get the correct data

Answer (score 1):

define a wrapper class:

```
export class PersonsWrapper{
    _embedded: { person: Person[]};
}
```

then use it for calls to Spring REST server:

```
httpClient.get<PersonsWrapper>(url).pipe(
    map(w => w._embedded.persons)
  ).subscribe(persons => ...);
```

Comment: It works only partially. "ID" is missing. That means class Person is not complete.

Comment: where is ID missing? you can define Person class like whatever you receive from server. If server does not send ID, then it's something to configure in entity on server side.